# How to pass two data to Controller using Script?

Tags: javascript, php

I have script like this:

```
delete_event: function() {
    if (this.id != 0) {
        var url = base_url + "event/delete_event_data/" + this.id + this.event_id;
        location.href = url;
    }
    else {
        alert('Please Select Event');
    }
},
```

I want to pass id and event id to following controller:

```
public function delete_event_data($id,$event_id) {
    $result = $this->event_model->delete_event_data($id);
    if ($result == TRUE) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success-msg', ' Event Data  Successfully Deleted. ');
        redirect('event');
    } else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('failure-msg', ' ERROR! Something went Wrong. ');
        redirect('event');
    }
}
```

I have done above but it doesn't work..
Please guide me..

Comment: I think it should be `this.id + '/'+ this.event_id;` instead of `this.id + this.event_id;`, Also which language is `$result = $this->event_model->delete_event_data($id);`?

Comment: what is your routing?

Comment: Which framework are you using and in framework this is not a way to get the parameters as I know.

Comment: i am using codeigniter frame work...

Comment: @satpal- thats php of codeigniter framework